# Statement List issue with Recursive Descent Parser tree

Tags: vb.net, parsing, recursion

I'm trying to write a simple Recursive Descent Parser.
The goal is to make a syntax tree of classes for each node.
The BNF grammar for my little language is:

```
<program> ::= <program> <statement>
           | <statement>

<statement> ::= if <value> then <program> end
             |  msg <value>

<value> ::= '0'
         |  '1'
```

and my test program:

```
if 1 then msg 0 end
```

The problem occurs when the parser is done with parsing the statement list (code block) between **IF** and **END**, it looks for the next statement before it can end the if statement with **END**

How is this normally done?
I tried to google an example that does this "if  then  end" type of thing but failed to find a good example.

My code is written in VB but should be readable for programmers that use other languages too. Any pseudo-code or example for this situation would be helpful.

To test my code just copy-paste this script in a *.vbs file on your desktop and double click it:

```
class program_statement
    public stmt
    public stmts
    sub execute
        stmt.execute
        if not(stmts is nothing) then stmts.execute
    end sub
end class

class IF_value_THEN_program_END
    public value
    public program
    sub execute
        if value = "1" then program.execute
    end sub
end class

class MSG_value
    public value
    sub execute
        msgbox value.value
    end sub
end class

class value
    public value
end class

'----------------------------------------------

function P
    set P = new program_statement
    set P.stmt = S
    if token = "" then
        set P.stms = nothing
    else
        set P.stms = P()
    end if
end function

function S
    if token = "if" then
        advance
        set S = new IF_value_THEN_program_END
        set S.value = V
        expect("then")
        set S.program = P
        expect("end")
    elseif token = "msg" then
        advance
        set S = new MSG_value
        set S.value = V
    else
        warning "expected: if, msg"
    end if
end function

function V
    if token = "0" or token = "1" then
        Set V = new value
        V.value = token
        advance
    else
        warning "expected: 0, 1"
    end if
end function

'----------------------------------------------

sub warning(message)
    msgbox message, vbexclamation, pionter & "=" & token
    wscript.quit
end sub

sub advance
    pionter = pionter + 1
end sub

function token
    if pionter-1 < ubound(TEST) then token = TEST(pionter)
end function

sub expect(input)
    if token = input then
        advance
    else
        warning "expected: " & input
    end if
end sub

'----------------------------------------------

TEST = split("if 1 then msg 0 end")
pionter = lbound(TEST)

Set My_Program = P
My_Program.execute
```

Comment: Ok, what i have done for now:

add array of objects for statements